# Expose webservice information to SCOM / WMI

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, monitoring

What would be the best way to expose information from an ASP.NET webservice to SCOM or WMI?  I'm interested in basically exposing performance information so the service can be monitored: ie. get a metric of calls processed per hour, total calls per day, etc.

**EDIT:** This would have to run under standard ASP.NET permissions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to write a WMI provider to expose info to WMI - there's [an example on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WMIProviderExtensions.aspx). An alternative, possibly simpler, would be to expose some custom performance counters as outlined [in this article](http://www.ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/07/wmi.html?page=2).